# Controlling hundreds of motors using an arduino uno

Tags: arduino, motor-controller, arduino-uno

I'm trying to build a haptic feedback suit, which requires me to control over about 576 vibration motors (24x24), using an arduino uno. I have no idea how to do this because the uno has only 13 gpio pins... Does anybody have suggestions as to how to go about this?

EDIT:
I don't think that the arduino UNO is capable of handling this task..
I'd appreciate it if you could suggest another microcontroller to use.
And also, if i can use a raspberry pi.

EDIT2: I need 524 Analog outputs

Comment: You could start by looking at GPIO expanders and Multiplexers.

Comment: Why specifically did you pick an Uno for this?

Comment: Find a chip that can control a more reasonable number of them and make a lot of copies of the board with that, cooperating as a network.   Needless to say you don't have the funding to actually do this in the quantity you mentioned.  But you might make three copies of the board or something to demonstrate the idea.  Depending on your control need, any of multi-channel PWM controllers, high pin count MCU's or FPGAs could be an option, given the perspective this seems to be asked from you should probably limit yourself to the first two so that you get something working you can demonstrate.

Comment: There is no sensible way to do this with an Uno

Comment: How many quantization bits per haptic excitation 1? 4? 8?  If 8, then you need a dual-port memory to write like video memory but depends on the latency you need/want? 10 ~ 60 fps ?  This must go in your design spec with other attributes like size/cost. before you even say Uno.  Otherwise, you may need to change your mind.

Comment: I just switched from doing software projects to Electronic ones.. and i chose the UNO cuz that's the only thing i know how to use.... And i'll map the analog output of the motors to the analog input of the sensors... And i'll update the values to be given to the motors about  30 times per second... Upon retrospection, the UNO doesn't look good for this. So, i'll use the raspberry pi, but i still am not aware about how to go forward with this

Comment: You might be able to use a TFT/LED/LCD controller, as embedded into stm32 or xmc4000, and drive the motors as a matrix, and basically turn them on and off as of they were pixels. Plenty of micros with matrix LED controllers which could potentially reduce your pin count and wiring to 24+24.

Comment: How much current do these motors use? Trying to find find a multichannel driver, to avoid having 576 switching transistors... How many motors will be activated at the same time? Maybe they can be multipexed.

Comment: you could use a WS2811 addressable LED driver to drive motors, instead of LEDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever MCU you use, it is unlikely to have 576 available GPIO pins.

One approach would be to devote 10 pins (one byte plus two control pins) and use 72 [74HC595](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC74HC595-D.PDF) shift registers (plus one driver per motor, of course). You could update the matrix with 72 clock cycles, bit-banged, and then update all the motor controls simultaneously with a single clock edge.

Whether the UNO is fast enough to do anything usable with that amount of data per update is another question, but update speed is probably usable.

Another approach would be to daisy-chain all 72 shift registers and use a single data pin, which would allow use of on-chip SPI hardware. With the addition of buffers you should be able to get the clock frequency up into the MHz range, so again millisecond-range updates could be possible, with only 3 pins (but getting it to work reliably might be a bit trickier).

In either case, excellent and well-thought-out circuit layout is essential. Turning on 576 motors simultaneously (with the associated surge looking more like 10x that) has potential to cause vexing issues.

Comment: Umm.... Yeah i doubt that the arduino UNO will be fast enough to handle. Will a raspberry pi 3b fare well in that respect?

Also.. I don't think that it is possible to give out analog outputs for each of those pins. But controlling the speed of each individual motor is essential, to this project. And so i'm gonna need another way around it... Thanks for the solution BTW

Comment: Umm not mentioning you need 576 **ANALOG** outputs is a major omission. That's also n times the data storage. Maybe look at using an FPGA to provide PWM outputs on many pins (then use a number of them).

Comment: Something like TLC5947 SPI-controlled multichannel PWM LED driver could work, but the OP would have to say how much current each motor will use.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I don't think OP really _needs_ analog outputs. It sounds more like he/she is thinking that having analog output is the only way to control speed of the motor. In which case this entire project is more like a wishful thinking without basic required knowledge.